# how do I make a query which references other rows in a resultset?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

The question is best asked with an example.

I have a table

```
id   |    name      |   attr
1    |     foo      |     a
2    |     bar      |     a    
3    |     baz      |     b
```

and I want a query `give me all the rows which share the same attr as 'name==foo'`, and thus returns

```
id   |    name      |   attr
1    |     foo      |     a
2    |     bar      |     a
```

because foo has attr=a, as does bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.attr = t.attr and t1.name = 'foo'
)
```

Note that this solution would also properly work if `'foo'` had more than one attribute.

For performance, you want an index on `(attr, name)`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.attr = (select t2.attr from t t2 where t.name = 'foo');
```

Comment: @pinoyyid . . . So much for being first ;)